# MATLAB 1/Inf default?

Tags: matlab, precision, default-value

I am writing code with MATLAB 2015b and `1/Inf=0` in this case. I'd like to know, has this always been the case for MATLAB or do I run the risk of a user who is running a previous MATLAB version of obtaining a different output? Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inf.html) end off by saying:

> **Introduced before R2006a**

I interpret that as it being a fairly safe bet to assume `1/Inf==0` holds in older versions of MATLAB

Answer (score 0):

The result of `1/Inf` is defined by manufacturers that comply or not to the IEEE standard. A quick search on Google gave the following

> `1/inf` gives `NaN` (Not A Number)

from [this source](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~mignotte/IFT2425/Matlab.pdf) edited in Canadian French in 1998.

Somehow between 1998 and 2006, the result of `1/Inf` changed - but honestly, who runs an 2002 Matlab engine anymore?

Comment: My oldest version still running - R2007b on Windows - gives `1/Inf = 0`.